# Xamarin forms: How to convert a picture path to mediafile?

Tags: image, file-upload, xamarin.forms

I have a picture file path and I am trying to upload this picture to server. When I upload this picture to server I need it's `GetStream()` value. I will show a sample code, that I have used in another place:

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()), "\"file\"", $"\"{_mediaFile.Path}\"");
var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(new Uri("My REST API"), content);

if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
   //Success
}
```

Where `_mediaFile` is a `MediaFile`

```
private MediaFile _mediaFile;
```

**But currently, I have only the picture path. So is there any way to convert the picture path to `MediaFile` or anyway way to get the `GetStream()` value of the picture path?**

Comment: What kind of image path do you have? is it in the native file managers?

Comment: Sample path: C:\Users\sonub\AppData\Local\Packages\com.pagematics.listpmcustomer_hcgbetyqs63kp\LocalState\business-process - Copy (7).jpg

Comment: So the image is in your computer and not your mobile device?

Comment: @G.hakim Both, Can you tell why I am getting the following error.
`The name 'File' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @G.hakim tried adding using System.IO and System.IO.File, no luck

Comment: Well are you trying to do this in Xamarin Forms .Net Standard library or a PCL?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186762/discussion-between-sreejith-sree-and-g-hakim).

Comment: According to the MSDN Documentation, System.IO.File is not supported in PCL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample method to upload an image to API.

```
private async void UploadImage()
{
    //variable
            var url = "yourUrl.com";
        var filePath = "path/to/file.ext";

            try
            {
                //read file into upfilebytes array
                var fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

                //create new HttpClient and MultipartFormDataContent and add our file, and StudentId
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                MultipartFormDataContent content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                ByteArrayContent byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(upfilebytes);
                content.Add(byteContent, "File", "filename.ext");


                //upload MultipartFormDataContent content async and store response in response var
                var response =
                    await client.PostAsync(url, content);

                //read response result as a string async into json var
                var responsestr = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                //debug
                Debug.WriteLine(responsestr);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //debug
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception Caught: " + e.ToString());

                return;
            }
}
```

Comment: Getting the same error, 'The name 'File' does not exist in the current context'

Comment: Should I add any nuget package for getting the 'File'?

Comment: tried adding `using System.IO` and `System.IO.File`, no luck

Comment: In what project/class are you hsing this? Is it a Xamarin.Forms solution? Have you tried to clean/rebuild the soolution? Or reopen visual studio?

Comment: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/7578/how-to-use-system-io-file-or-similar-for-cross-platform-projects-in-pcls

Comment: Is there any other way other than converting to .Net standard? When I convert getting a lot of errors.

Comment: I am using this for converting to `.Net standard` https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tafuji.pcl2netstandard

Answer (score 0):

[File.Open(path)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.open?view=netframework-4.7.2) will return a `FileStream`

Comment: Should I add any nuget package for getting the 'File'?

Comment: Getting 'The name 'File' does not exist in the current context' error